# Prove that the complement of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove that the complement of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

---

I have no idea how can I do that. If $\mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is connected then the proof is easy which is not true. somebody help me please.thanks for your time.

Comment: It turns out this question has been asked and answered [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145912/formal-proof-that-mathbbr2-setminus-mathbbq-times-mathbbq-subset).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any $(x,y) \in X = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$, at least one of $x, y \notin \mathbb{Q}$. We can always connect it to $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \in X$ by a polygon path in $X$:

$$\begin{cases}
(x,y) \to (x, \sqrt{2} ) \to (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}), &\text{ for }x \notin \mathbb{Q}\\
(x,y) \to (\sqrt{2}, y ) \to (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}), &\text{ for }x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \notin \mathbb{Q} 
\end{cases}$$

Any two points in $X$ can be connected by a polygonal path by joining their paths to $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and hence $X$ is path connected.

**Update**

In another answer, there is an interesting statement:

> And $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ where $A$ is countable is always path connected.

Let me give a proof of this statement and hence an alternative proof for this question.

For any $\vec{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$, consider following collection of unit vectors:

$$X_1 = \left\{ \pm \frac{\vec{y} - \vec{x}_1}{|\vec{y} - \vec{x}_1|} : \vec{y} \in A\right\} \subset S^{1}$$

Since $A$ is countable, so does $X_1$. This means $S^{1} \setminus X_1 \ne \emptyset$. In fact, $S^{1} \setminus X_1$ is uncountable. Pick any unit vector $\vec{n}_1$ from $S^{1} \setminus X_1$ and construct a line $l_1$ passing through $\vec{x}_1$ in the direction of $\vec{n}_1$:

$$l_1 = \left\{ \vec{x}_1 + t \vec{n}_1 : t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

By construction, it is clear $\vec{x}_1 \in l_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$.

For another $\vec{x}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$, a similar argument allow us to construct another set of unit vectors $X_2$, unit vectors $\vec{n}_2$ and line $l_2$ such that $\vec{x}_2 \in l_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$. 
Furthermore, since $S^1 \setminus ( X_1 \cup X_2 )$ is infinite, we can choose a $\vec{n}_2$ not in the direction of $\pm \vec{n}_1$.

Under this restriction, $l_1 \not\parallel l_2$ and intersect at some point $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$. The polygon path $\vec{x}_1 \to \vec{y} \to \vec{x}_2$ lies completely outside $A$ and hence $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is path connected.

**Update 2**

It turns out this question has been asked and answered before. 
A much simpler argument for the statement can be found at JDH's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145958/59379) there. The basic idea is what TonyK given in the comment below and what is in Seirios' answer.

Comment: The proof in your update can be replaced by this: For any two distinct points $x_1,x_2$, there are an uncountable number of disjoint circular arcs from $x_1$ to $x_2$. They can't all contain a point in $A$, otherwise $A$ would be uncountable too.

Comment: @TonyK, thanks but I think a link to JDH's answer is more appropriate. His use of keyword "foliation of continuum many paths" instead of "disjoint" make the whole argument much more precise and easier to visualize.

Comment: If you ask me, "foliation of continuum many paths" introduces unnecessary formality.

Comment: What are $S^1$  and $S^2$ ?

Comment: @Myath $S^1 = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the unit circle in the plane. Similarly, $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the unit sphere. The $S^2$ you see before is a typo, it should be $S^1$.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use the fact that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable. And $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus A$ where $A$ is countable is always path connected$\implies$ connected.

Comment: "You will have to use the fact..." Not true, as Petr Pudlák shows.

Comment: @TonyK, yes, there are other proof methods, but this answer is correct nonetheless. It looks to me a lot like Serios', by the way.

Comment: I think if one change the wordings from "You will have to use the fact" to "You can use the fact", the intention of this proof will be clearer. In any event, I've included a proof of the statement "$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ where $A$ is countable is always path connected" in my own answer ;-p

Answer (score 5):

You can easily show that $S=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is [pathwise connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathwise_connected#Path_connectedness), which is stronger than connectedness. Fix an irrational number $\alpha$; it suffices one connect any point of $S$ by a path in $S$ to $(\alpha,\alpha)$. If $(x,y)\in S$ with $x$ irrational, make a straight line path from $(x,y)$ to $(x,\alpha)$ and then from there straight to $(\alpha,\alpha)$. If $x$ is rational then $y$ must be irrational, and a similar path from $(x,y)$ to $(\alpha,y)$ and then to $(\alpha,\alpha)$ works.

Comment: This is the same answer as those of achille hui and Petr Pudlák (+1) which I did not see when I started typing mine.

Answer (score 4):

This actually seems to be true for any subset $S\subsetneq \mathbb{R}$.

Hint: Can you connect any two points $(x_1,y_1)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (S\times S)$ and  $(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (S\times S)$ by a path?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \mathbb{Q}^2$. There are uncountably many disjoint paths between $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (you can exhibit such a family). Therefore, you find path connectedness by cardinality.

Comment: I can't see the cardinality argument. Sure, there are uncountably many paths, but they could still all contain a rational point.

Comment: @PeterWebb JDH's answer to [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145912/formal-proof-that-mathbbr2-setminus-mathbbq-times-mathbbq-subset) before uses same idea but easier to understand. The key is the paths can be chosen to be disjoint (except at the end points).

Comment: @Peter: No they couldn't, because that would give you an uncountable number of distinct rational points.

Comment: I get it now, thanks to achille and TonyK.