# Showing pathwise connectedness of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, connectedness

How can I show that a set is pathwise-connected?

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I guess this holds only if you drop the word "either"

Comment: If you wanted to ask the question with "or" rather than "either - or" (as suggested in the previous comment), then there already are several posts about this question. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013994/let-x-be-a-subspace-of-mathbb-r2-consisting-of-points-that-at-least-one-is-r) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577514/show-that-x-x-y-in-mathbbr2-mid-x-in-mathbbq-text-or-y-in-ma).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider polygonal paths parallel to the axes.

Comment: *axes* plural... but, yes

Comment: @BrianO: I've edited my post, I am sorry I misspelled it :)

Comment: I noticed, good :) That should be all the answer needed.